# How to create a Caesar's encryption disk using LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, circles

How can I create a Caesar's encryption disk with LaTeX?

[image: Caesar's encryption disk]

I guess, the ultimate solution would take a arbitrary list of letters and calculate the spaces and angles for each letter automatically. So if I pass 4 letters to it, each space should have 90 degrees.

Comment: This looks like *fun*. Can we add that to the tag?

Comment: Done, added 'fun' :-)

Comment: What have you tried so far? MWE? Do you want to give a list of letters? The number of letters? What should happen when the number is greater than 26?

Comment: I have no idea how to tackle this problem, so there is no MWE yet. I could imagine it as the following: 

\ceasar[circleouterwidth=5cm]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g} with character for the inner and the outer circle. Giving two separate lists could allow to use math symbols as well or Greek characters.

There should not be a problem if there are more than 26 chars.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, well it could be done using an optional parameter for the shift, let's say [0] for no shift or [13] for Rot13, etc.

Comment: Next challenge - build an Enigma machine in `TeX`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine

Comment: Go Lahead, at least with LuaTeX it could actually work!

Comment: Related [A circular table? (where the rows form concentric circles)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179488/35864).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

#### Commands

- `\drawCaesarsDisk` that works with a number of letters (only A to Z)
- `\drawCaesarsList` that works with one list for both rings or two different lists

#### Keys

- `inner radius`/`middle radius`/`outer radius`

  - Improvements: Specify inner radius and add `inner height` and `outer height` respectively to calculate the actual radii.
  - Improvements: With these heights, scale the letters so that they fit right into one ring segment.
- `number of letters` *(only `\drawCaesarsDisk`)*
- `inner letters` and `outer letters` *(only `\drawCaesarsList`):* If only `inner letters` is specified the letters in the outer ring will be the same as in the inner ring.
- `shift`

#### Parameters (both commands)

- First (optional): Key=Values for the disk.
- Second (mandatory): where the Disk is placed.

#### Improvement:

- Radii/font-size calculation (see above)
- Starting with the first letter at the north position or right of it (possible style)
- Adding styles for circles, separators, letters, etc.
- *Bug:* The List command breaks with

  ```
  ! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgfmath@x
  ```

  when 46 or more letters are specified.
- I forgot something …

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    /caesar/.cd,
    inner radius/.store in=\qrr@caesar@innerR,
    middle radius/.store in=\qrr@caesar@middleR,
    outer radius/.store in=\qrr@caesar@outerR,
    inner letters/.store in=\qrr@caesar@innerL,
    outer letters/.store in=\qrr@caesar@outerL,
    number of letters/.code=\pgfmathtruncatemacro\qrr@caesar@number{#1},
    shift/.store in=\qrr@caesar@shift,
    % defaults:
    outer letters=,
    shift=0
}
\newcommand*{\drawCaesarsDisk}[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/caesar}{#1}%
    \foreach \radius in {\qrr@caesar@innerR,\qrr@caesar@middleR,\qrr@caesar@outerR}
        \draw (#2) circle [radius=\radius];
    \foreach \step in {0,...,\numexpr\qrr@caesar@number-1}{
        \draw[shift={(#2)}] (\step*360/\qrr@caesar@number:\qrr@caesar@innerR) -- (\step*360/\qrr@caesar@number:\qrr@caesar@outerR);
        \node[shift={(#2)},rotate=(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number-90] at ({(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number}:{.5*(\qrr@caesar@innerR)+.5*(\qrr@caesar@middleR)} ) {\@Alph{\numexpr26-\step}};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\pgf@temp{mod(\step+\qrr@caesar@shift,\qrr@caesar@number)}%
        \node[shift={(#2)},rotate=(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number-90] at ({(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number}:{.5*(\qrr@caesar@outerR)+.5*(\qrr@caesar@middleR)} ) {\@Alph{\numexpr26-\pgf@temp}};
    }
    \endgroup
}
\newcount\qrr@caesar@c
\newcommand*{\drawCaesarsList}[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/caesar}{#1}%
    \foreach \radius in {\qrr@caesar@innerR,\qrr@caesar@middleR,\qrr@caesar@outerR}
        \draw (#2) circle [radius=\radius];
    \qrr@caesar@c=0\relax
    \foreach \element in \qrr@caesar@innerL {\global\advance\qrr@caesar@c1}
    \ifx\pgfutil@empty\qrr@caesar@outerL
        \let\qrr@caesar@outerL\qrr@caesar@innerL
    \fi
    \edef\qrr@caesar@number{\number\qrr@caesar@c}%
    \foreach \innerLetter[count=\step from 0] in \qrr@caesar@innerL {
        \draw[shift={(#2)}] (\step*360/\qrr@caesar@number:\qrr@caesar@innerR) -- (\step*360/\qrr@caesar@number:\qrr@caesar@outerR);
        \node[shift={(#2)},rotate=-(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number-90] at ({-(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number}:{.5*(\qrr@caesar@innerR)+.5*(\qrr@caesar@middleR)} ) {\innerLetter};
    }
    \foreach \outerLetter[count=\step@ from 0] in \qrr@caesar@outerL {
        \ifnum\step@=\qrr@caesar@number\breakforeach\fi
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\step{mod(\step@+\qrr@caesar@shift,\qrr@caesar@number)}%
        \node[shift={(#2)},rotate=-(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number-90] at ({-(\step+.5)*360/\qrr@caesar@number}:{.5*(\qrr@caesar@outerR)+.5*(\qrr@caesar@middleR)} ) {\outerLetter};
    }
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawCaesarsDisk[
    inner radius=2cm,
    middle radius=2cm+1.3em,
    outer radius=2cm+3em,
    number of letters=26,
    shift=13,
    ]{0,0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawCaesarsList[
    inner radius=.5cm,
    middle radius=.5cm+1.3em,
    outer radius=.5cm+3em,
    inner letters={a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
    outer letters={A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
    ]{2,0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawCaesarsList[
    inner radius=2cm,
    middle radius=2cm+1.3em,
    outer radius=2cm+3em,
    inner letters={a,...,z,A,B,...,T},%,U,V,W,X,Y,Z},
    shift=26,
    ]{0,0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! However I get an error: "! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.58     ]{0,0}

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I have added some explanation since you made your comment. I also updated the solution to work with the 2.10 version of TikZ. The problem was a parsing error that was already discussed in other questions. And to clarify: Yes, you can give two (possibly different) lists *and* you can specify a `shift`.

Comment: You are awesome! :-)

Comment: An alternative way of getting the length of a `\foreach` list is: `\foreach \x [count=\c from 1, remember=\c] in {A,...,Z}{}`. Then `\c` holds the length of the list.

Answer (score 22):

Here is what I've done so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\alphsize}{26}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{360/\alphsize}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\op}{98 + \ang/2 - 1.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{\ang + \ang*\d}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ep}{\op + \ang*\d}

    \foreach \x in {0,\ang,...,360} {
      \draw[gray] (\x:8em) -- (\x:12em);
    }

    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {A,...,Z} {
      \node[rotate=\ang - \ang*\xi] at (\op - \ang*\xi:11em) {\Large\x};
      \node[rotate=\e - \ang*\xi] at (\ep - \ang*\xi:9em) {\Large\x};
    }

    \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(12em);
    \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) circle(10em);
    \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(8em);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Caesar latin circle]

Answer (score 18):

Here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{encrypted}
\newcounter{original}

\newcommand{\increase}[1]{%command to increase a counter by 1 modulo 26
\ifthenelse{\arabic{#1}<26}{\addtocounter{#1}{1}}{\setcounter{#1}{1}}
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{encrypted}{7}
\setcounter{original}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw(0,0)circle(5)circle(7)circle(9);
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,26}
{
\draw(\x*360/26:5)--(\x*360/26:9);
\node at (\x*360/26+360/26+180/26:6){\Alph{encrypted}};
\node at (\x*360/26+360/26+180/26:8){\Alph{original}};
\increase{encrypted}
\increase{original}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really promising. Is there an easy way to take just a list of characters instead of hard-coding the 26 letters?

Comment: @Toscho I have added the picture for you. I hope you don't mind. `:-)`

Answer (score 15):

Just 4 fun with PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\makeatletter
\def\N{26}

\begin{document}
% speficy the angular distance between the 2 sets of alphabets
\def\offset{13}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psforeach{\r} {2,3,4}{\pscircle{\r}}
    \degrees[\N]
    \psforeach{\t}{65,66,..,90}{%
        \psline(2;\the\psLoopIndex)(4;\the\psLoopIndex)
        \pstVerb{/angle {\the\psLoopIndex\space 0.5 add} bind def}%
        \rput{!angle 6.5 sub}(!3.5 angle \pst@angleunit PtoC){\char\t\relax}
        \rput{!angle \offset\space add 6.5 sub}(!2.5 angle \offset\space add \pst@angleunit PtoC){\char\t\relax}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animated version

To be funner!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\makeatletter
\def\N{26}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+1}{\N}{%
% speficy the angular distance between the 2 sets of alphabets
\def\offset{\i}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psforeach{\r} {2,3,4}{\pscircle{\r}}
    \degrees[\N]
    \psforeach{\t}{65,66,..,90}{%
        \psline(2;\the\psLoopIndex)(4;\the\psLoopIndex)
        \pstVerb{/angle {\the\psLoopIndex\space 0.5 add} bind def}%
        \rput{!angle 6.5 sub}(!3.5 angle \pst@angleunit PtoC){\char\t\relax}
        \rput{!angle \offset\space add 6.5 sub}(!2.5 angle \offset\space add \pst@angleunit PtoC){\char\t\relax}
    }
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

### Warning

If we invoke `\degrees[<value other than 360>]` previously, conversion with `\pst@angleunit` is needed for representing points in RPN notation but it is NOT need for representing rotation angle. See the following code snippet.

```
\rput{!angle 6.5 sub}(!3.5 angle \pst@angleunit PtoC){\t}
```

It is funny? Don't ask me! I just knew this feature several minutes ago!

One more feature, unlike `\foreach \t in {A,...,Z}{}` that produces a correct result, `\psforeach{\t}{A,..,Z}{}`  produces a weird output!